# Arrange items of different heights in a grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have various UI components of varying dimensions, which I am putting up together in a page. I want to arrange them horizontally in a grid, where each row should be equal to the height of the component which has the maximum height in that row. There are no fixed number of columns for each row. Components should be placed next to each other without their dimensions being changed, and should automatically wrap to the next row if there is no space left for that component in that row.

I tried using bootstrap, but I must specify column width for each component like  `col-xs-number`, which I can't do as I can't freeze the number of items in a row.

Edit: The application uses bootstrap version 3, so can't use V4.

Is this possible?

Comment: take a look at display:flex + flex-wrap:wrap; or https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/  ... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without any kind of Bootstrap, just using `display: inline-block` for the elements.

Below is a demo where I add 12 elements of varying heights in a container div, where the width of the container div is set to a random value every time it is run to show how it will wrap differently each time.

```js
var heights = [100, 20, 80, 140, 65, 90, 30, 70, 130, 55, 75, 100];
for (var i = 0; i < heights.length; i++) {
  $('#x').append($('<div style="height:' + heights[i] + 'px"></div>'))
}
var w = Math.floor((Math.random() * 400) + 100);
$('#x').css("width", w + "px");
```

```css
#x div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  width: 50px;
  background: green;
  margin: 10px;
}

#x {
  border: solid 1px #888
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<div id="x"></div>
<hr>
```

Comment: I had done the exact same thing, but the issue with this is that all items don't align to the bottom of the row, so it looks uneven.

Comment: Oh I did't see the `vertical-align` property you have added. `vertical-align: bottom` does the trick for me. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way I can centre each element so that it leaves equal space on top and bottom of the row?

Comment: Uh that was easy, `vertical-align: middle`!

Answer (score 0):

Check flexbox, bootstrap 4 is using flexbox, so you can have columns without numbers.

Example:

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
}

.col:first-of-type{
  background:white;
}


.col:nth-of-type(2){
  background:green;
}

.col:last-of-type{
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='container'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">First</div>
    <div class="col">Second</div>
    <div class="col">Third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```